# Каким образом можно динамично центрировать данный TexView? (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

У меня есть TextView который выводит информацию о текущей погоде, через код к этому числу прибавляется значок градуса `currentDegree.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(jsonObjectMain.getDouble("temp")) + "°"));` - вот таким образом, всё бы ничего, но при отображении положительной и двузначной температуры, вся эта конструкция немного съезжает влево.

**Пример:**

[image: Не обращайте внимания на дополнительные TextView, они необходимы для отладки.]

И Android Studio всё делает верно, центрирует **TextView** по середине, но мне необходимо, чтобы цифры были по середине а сам знак градуса как бы стоял в сторонке.

**Пример из другого приложения:**
[image: Такого результата я пытаюсь добиться.]

Здесь минус не толкает цифру **5** а знак градуса как приспешник стоит в сторонке, а текущая температура всегда по середине, каким образом можно сделать так же в моём случае?

Я уже и делал отдельные **TextView** для этих элементов, и писал костыль который подвигает эту всю конструкцию считывая количество символов и опираясь на это делает необходимые пробелы, но опять же это всё выглядело криво и не практично.

**XML код моего TextView, компоновка построена при помощи ConstraintLayout:**

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_degree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bebasbold"
        android:shadowColor="@color/black_color"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowRadius="10"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textSize="160sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Может быть у кого-то есть альтернативные способы решения данной проблемы?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: По идее самый нормальный способ - TexView по центру для числа, и TexView слева от него для знака и TexView справа для значка градуса

Comment: Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы градус следовал за TextView а не наоборот? Если я делаю зависимость знака градуса по одной из сторон цифр градусов, то цифры градусов просто притягиваются к значку градусов (Constraint Layout).

Comment: Не вполне ясно что и как именно вы делаете. Я имею в виду расположение числа по центру (т.е. привязать все стороны к родителю). Оставшиеся два TexView привязать только в центральному TexView (верх, низ и начало/конец в зависимости от того, что именно привязываем). TexView числа привязываться к TexView знака и градуса не должно.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую данный вариант.

Comment: Спасибо! После пары десятка фраз по типу "какого хрена здесь минус" и часа сидения в Андроид Студии проблема была решена.